# Groovy for loop that compares records from database

Tags: database, for-loop, groovy

I have a database with 1 table that holds hundreds of records. I need to make a for loop in groovy script that compares first record with second record, second record with third record, etc. i need to compare length changes between records and print out all changes that is higher than 30. Example - first record 30m, second record 40m, third record 100m. It will print out second-third record.
I dont know amount of records in table, so i dont know how to create for loop. Any suggestions?
Also records has ip. Each ip can be multiple times and i need to compare all records in each ip.

record 1:

```
port_nbr | 1                          
pair     | pairA
length   | 30.00
add_date | 2020-06-16 00:01:13.237164
```

record 2:

```
port_nbr | 1                              
pair     | pairA
length   | 65.00
add_date | 2020-06-16 00:02:13.237164
```

record 3:

```
port_nbr | 2                              
pair     | pairc
length   | 65.00
add_date | 2020-06-16 00:02:13.237164
```

I expect that for loop checks if current record port_nbr is the same with next record, if yes, then it checks if pair is same and if its the same, then he compares if length changed for 30+m. In this case it would output that there is 30+m change in 1/2 record. After outputing it, then it would compare second record and third record. But they doesnt have same port_nbr and pair, so i expect it to start comparing again all port_nbr that is 2 with all following records.
There could be even 10 records with port_nbr 1, but with different pairs. I need to check for pairs aswell and only then compare lengths.

My code at this moment:

```
import java.sql.*;
import groovy.sql.Sql

class Main{
static void main(String[] args) {

def dst_db1 = Sql.newInstance('connection.........')
dst_db1.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false)


def sql = (" select d.* from (select d.*, lead((case when length <> 'N/A' then length else length_to_fault end)::float) over (partition by port_nbr, pair order by port_nbr, pair, d.add_date) as lengthh from diags d)d limit 10")

def lastRow = [id:-1, port_nbr:-1, pair:'', lengthh:-1.0]
dst_db1.eachRow( sql ) {row ->

if( row.port_nbr == lastRow.port_nbr && row.pair == lastRow.pair){
BigDecimal lengthChange =
new BigDecimal(row.lengthh ? row.lengthh : 0 ) - new BigDecimal(lastRow.lengthh ? lastRow.lengthh :0 )

if( lengthChange > 30.0){
print "Port ${row.port_nbr}, ${row.pair} length change: $lengthChange"
println "/tbetween row ID ${lastRow.id} and ${row.id}"
}
lastRow = row
}else{
println "Key Changed"
lastRow = row
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: use a `while` loop. please edit your question and provide the input data example and expected result.

Comment: use a `for` loop

Comment: i added some example

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will report length changes > 30 within the same port_nbr and pair.

```
def sql = 'Your SQL here.' // Should include "order by pair, port_nbr, date"

def lastRow = [id:-1, port_nbr:-1, pair:'', length:-1.0]
dst_db1.eachRow( sql ) { row ->

  if ( row.port_nbr == lastRow.port_nbr && row.pair == lastRow.pair ) {
    BigDecimal lengthChange = 
      new BigDecimal( row.length ) - new BigDecimal( lastRow.length )

    if ( lengthChange > 30.0 ) {
        print "Port ${row.port_nbr}, ${row.pair} length change: $lengthChange"
        println "\tbetween row ID ${lastRow.id} and ${row.id}"
    }
    lastRow = row
  } else {
    println "Key changed"
    lastRow = row
  }
}
```

To run the above code without a database I prefixed it with this test code:

```
class DstDb1 {

  def eachRow ( sql, closure ) {
    rows.each( closure )
  }
  
  def rows = [
    [id: 1, port_nbr: 1, pair: 'pairA', length:  30.00 ],
    [id: 2, port_nbr: 1, pair: 'pairA', length:  65.00 ],
    [id: 3, port_nbr: 1, pair: 'pairA', length:  70.00 ],
    [id: 4, port_nbr: 1, pair: 'pairA', length:  75.00 ],
    [id: 5, port_nbr: 1, pair: 'pairB', length: 130.00 ],
    [id: 6, port_nbr: 1, pair: 'pairB', length: 165.00 ],
    [id: 7, port_nbr: 1, pair: 'pairB', length: 170.00 ],
    [id: 8, port_nbr: 1, pair: 'pairB', length: 175.00 ],
    [id: 9, port_nbr: 2, pair: 'pairC', length: 230.00 ],
    [id:10, port_nbr: 2, pair: 'pairC', length: 265.00 ],
    [id:11, port_nbr: 2, pair: 'pairC', length: 270.00 ],
    [id:12, port_nbr: 2, pair: 'pairC', length: 350.00 ]
  ]
}

DstDb1 dst_db1 = new DstDb1()
```

Running the test gives this result:

```
Key changed
Port 1, pairA length change: 35 between row ID 1 and 2
Key changed
Port 1, pairB length change: 35 between row ID 5 and 6
Key changed
Port 2, pairC length change: 35 between row ID 9 and 10
Port 2, pairC length change: 80 between row ID 11 and 12
```

Comment: But i have hudreds of records. ( all records are already sorted by ports_nbr) so i have to compare if first record has same port_nbr with second record. Then i need to compare if they has same pair (pairA-D) and only then i can  compare lengths... Example - there is 8 records with port_nbr 1... 6 of them are pairA, rest of them are pairB. So i need to compare length change between all port_nbr 1, pairA. Then i need to do the same thing with port_nbr 1, pairB. When there is no more left in port_nbr 1, then it keeps doing the same thing with port_nbr 2, 3, 4... etc

Comment: I've updated the answer with the assumption that you're only comparing lengths within a pair for each port, and that you're only interested in length changes between adjacent rows.

Comment: Hey! I see that you added rowSet where you writed some examples. I have unknown list of records, so i need to make something different in this case

Comment: I made select inside my code, that takes all records from database. It looks like this - ```dst_db1.eachRow("Select d.* from (select d.*, lead(length::float) over (partition by port_nbr, pair order by d.add_date) as next_length from diags d where length !='N/A')d")```

Comment: It makes order by date, pair, port. This select sorts all records, so i can easily write code about this records that i pulled out. But your code isnt working for me, because you added ```def rowSet```  where you insert values in code, but i have already pulled out all records with this select.

Comment: I forgot another }... Im sorry for fake alert.. But again, after that i got new error -  ```cannot compare java.lang.String with value ' ' and java.math.Bigdecimal with value '30' ``` In database length is char, but in select part i changed it to float like this - length::float. Maybe i have to change something in code aswell?

Comment: Is your query returning the length field as a string?

Comment: in select part i wrote - length::float, because in database length has char datatype and  i must change it somehow, so i can use numbers inside of it. This is my sql part - ```dst_db1.eachRow("Select d.* from (select d.*, lead(length::float) over (partition by port_nbr, pair order by d.add_date) as next_length from diags d where length !='N/A')d")``` I think it should be float all the time, after this

Comment: The error message seems to imply that lengthChange is a String. Try changing the line to this:
`BigDecimal lengthChange = new BigDecimal( row.length ) - new BigDecimal( lastRow.length )`

Comment: This works! No more errors. It printed out - Key changed. I searched up why it happened and then i saw your examples. I think i didnt explain this task enought to you. My idea was - first record and second record difference, then second record and third record difference and so on.  In your examples i see that you created script that compares first record with all other records in same port and pair.

Comment: You want to compare lengths between rows for different port+pair values?

Comment: everything that you did , but just compare different - first record with second, second with third, third with fourth , etc. You made script that compares first record with second, first with third, first with fourth.  I hope now you understand my  idea. Im really sorry if im bad at explaining

Comment: I cant expect that. Record amount can change. There could be 100 records, there could be 200 records. Number of records is random. I hope you understand my task. I tryed to make this script for a few weeks but couldnt do it... You already made me much closer to results.

Comment: I think you should change your query to use: `order by pair, port_nbr, a.add_date`. I'll update the answer to work as you'd with that sort order.

Comment: i hope you mean this - ```dst_db1.eachRow("Select d.* from (select d.*, lead(length::float) over (partition by port_nbr, pair order by d.pair, d.port_nbr, d.add_date) as next_length from diags d where length !='N/A')d")```

Comment: I have 2 columns - length and length_to_fault. Example - if in one record length is N/A, then number will be in length_to_fault. And if number is in length, then length_to_fault is N/A. My idea was to write script and test it on length only, because i didnt know how to make a select with both (length and length_to_fault). And i wanted to edit select after i created +- correct script for this task

Comment: I wanted to make script that could work on my task and then edit my select.. My idea is to make length and length_to_fault into one column, because they are the same, but if one column is empty, then other column will hold number. So i could try to make something like - ```sum(length, length_to_fault) as length, and then it should work fully?

Comment: Hey! Code is running without errors , but i think something might be wrong with if statements. When i execute script, it prints out - Key changed. It means, if statement never was true. But its not possible. I runned script where i just print out first 10 records. length was 52, 31, 46, 53 , 41, 45.83, 0, 0, 33 and 70. It should print out that between 7/8, 8/9 and 9/10 is length change higher than 30 in this case, but it just says - Key changed. I will update code with my current one